# How to diasble the HTML checker in the tests?

Tags: github, automated-tests

Running ["ScriptCheck", "OpenGraphCheck", "LinkCheck", "ImageCheck", "HtmlCheck"] on ["_site"] on *.html...

Checking 344 external links...

- _site/hi/building-community/index.html
  Ran on 257 files!

  - linking to internal hash #dont-tolerate-bad-actors that does not exist (line 585)
    act immediately
  - linking to internal hash #enforcing-your-code-of-conduct that does not exist (line 503)
    उन्हें जाने के लिए कहो
  - linking to internal hash #learning-to-say-no that does not exist (line 413)
    समझाइए क्यों
  - linking to internal hash #what-it-means-to-contribute that does not exist (line 412)
    योगदान करने के कई तरीके
  - linking to internal hash #writing-a-readme that does not exist (line 401)
    मैत्रीपूर्णREADME
  - linking to internal hash #writing-a-readme that does not exist (line 602)
    more than just a set of instructions
  - linking to internal hash #writing-your-contributing-guidelines that does not exist (line 403)
    योगदान CONTRIBUTING फ़ाइल  का उपयोग करके
- _site/hi/getting-paid/index.html

  - External link https://www.ashedryden.com/blog/the-ethics-of-unread-labor-and-the-oss-community failed: 404 No error

HTML-Proofer found 8 failures!

tried to merge the git repos but got the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.